# Is there a terminal command to open applications in a specific Desktop?

Tags: terminal, command-line, desktop

For example when I run `open -a Kodi` I'd like to be able to specify which Desktop I'd want the application to launch in.

Trying to avoid [dragging/dropping](https://i.imgur.com/RRqNEXv.gifv) to the desired workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can permanently assign an app to a Space by right-clicking the app in the dock > Options > Assign to... This Desktop.

[image]

A faster way to move it to any given Space is to grab the window's title bar, then use your regular shortcut to switch to the desired Space. By default that would be  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>*[number]*</kbd> 
See System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control if you've never set that up. [Note that it differentiates between the numbers above  qwerty & numbers on a 10-key pad & considers them different keys]

Comment: Options > Assign to... is no longer available.

Comment: @jherran - Since when? It's still available as of 10.11.4 Picture added.

Comment: Never mind. Will be out in 10.11 betas and thought that will be out now. I was wrong. As you say is still there.

Comment: I really hope they're not going to break Spaces any more than they already did when they added Mission Control :(

Comment: Hmmm... 10.11.5 has arrived in my updates... will report back... :/

Comment: @jherran - still there in 10.11.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe there is no known way to launch an application in a specific dock space (Desktop) using command line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).